# Tracing indices to original matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to trace the indices of `A2` with respect to `A1`. But I get an error. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A1 = np.array([[0.3, 1.2, 2],
     [3, 4, 5]]) # Shape 2 rows & 3 columns

A2 = np.array([0.3,1.2])
A=list(zip(*np.unravel_index(A2, np.array(A1).shape)))
print([A])
```

Error:

```
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in unravel_index

TypeError: only int indices permitted
```

Desired output:

```
[(0,0),(0,1)]
```

Comment: Reread what that function says about the `indices` argument.  Read the docs!

Comment: Just round off the values to int and you can get your desired output as indexes can't be float. Just use `A2 = np.array([0,1]) `.

Comment: The purpose is to use the exact values. Is there another way which can help generate indices corresponding to the original matrix?\

Comment: What happens if one of the numbers in `A2` appears multiple times in `A1`? Do you want to return just the first time it occurs or every time it occurs?

Comment: All the elements in ```A1``` are distinct and so are elements in ```A2```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the desired list of tuples:

```
A = [tuple(np.array(np.where(A1 == a)).ravel().tolist()) for a in A2]
```

For each element `a` in `A2`, it finds the index in `A1` using `np.where`. Then it converts the index to a tuple using `ravel`, `tolist` and `tuple`. Each index is automatically in the same list.